# .class calling error when compiling

Tags: java

I am getting a expected .class error while trying to compile the file to run my program. I have one java file(main) calling to another java file with the class name Sales.

HEre is my code for the two java files

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sales
{
    double product1 = 2.98;
    double product2 = 4.50;
    double product3 = 9.98;
    double product4 = 4.49;
    double product5 = 6.87;
    double sale = 0;
    public void printHello()
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a product number.");
    int userInput = input.nextInt();
        while(userInput != 0)
        {   
           if(userInput >= 1 && userInput <= 5)
            {
            switch(userInput)
            {
                 case 1: product1++;
                    sale += 2.98;

        System.out.print("How many were sold?");             
        userInput = input.nextInt();     
                     break;


            case 2: product2++;
                    sale += 4.50;


        System.out.print("How many were sold?");
        userInput = input.nextInt();        
                     break;


            case 3: product3++;
                    sale += 9.98;

        System.out.print("How many break; were sold?");
        userInput = input.nextInt();
                     break;




            case 4:product4++;
                    sale += 4.49;

        System.out.print("How many were sold?");
        userInput = input.nextInt(); 
                     break;



            case 5: product5++;
                    sale += 6.87;

        System.out.print("How many were sold?");
        userInput = input.nextInt(); 
                     break;


        }//end switch
        } //end if
        else if (userInput != 0)
        System.out.println("ERROR: Incorrect Product Number, Please Try Again");
        System.out.print("Please enter a Product Number");
        userInput = input.nextInt();
    }//end while 
} //end main
    public void printSales(double product1,double product2,double product3,double product4,double                    product5)
    {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Product 1: $%.2f\n", product1);
    System.out.printf("Product 2: $%.2f\n", product2);
    System.out.printf("Product 3: $%.2f\n", product3);
    System.out.printf("Product 4: $%.2f\n", product4);
    System.out.printf("Product 5: $%.2f\n", product5);
    System.out.printf("The total Cost is: %.2f\n", sale);
    } //end printSales
} //end class
```

then my main :

```
public class SalesTest
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Sales mySales = new Sales();    
    mySales.printHello();
    mySales.printSales();
}//end class    
}
```

Im trying to call public class Sales with public class SalesTest. When i try to compile SalesTest i get :

SalesTest.java:8:error: method printSales in class Sales cannot be applied to given types;
mySales.printSales();

required:double,double,double,double,double
found no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

How do i fix this?

Comment: Well the error message says it all, it needs 5 doubles and you didn't give it any doubles in the class SalesTest

Comment: You need to pass 5 doubles to printSales(), as it says in the method signature:     public void printSales(double product1,double product2,double product3,double product4,double                    product5). mySales.printSales(1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d); should work.

Comment: Ahh I see. I didnt realize that. Was trying to call it using double product1, etc. Thank you very much. Now that that is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not the same method.

To call a method defined as:

`public void printSales(double product1, double product2, double product3, double product4, double product5)`

You need to use something like:
`mySales.printSales( 0, 0.0, 0d, 0f, Double.valueOf(0) );`

(Any of those forms can be used to match a double in a method signature in java)

When you call with:
`mySales.printSales();`

You end up trying to call something like:
`public void printSales()`

Which you don't have, so you get an error.

This is called method overloading.  It isn't just the name of the method that must match but it's signature.  That includes the parameters.

Comment: I agree, this isn't helpful at all

Comment: This is the correct answer. Upvoted to reverse my earlier downvote.